# Copy resources from a dependency jar or war file in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have multiple war files in different projects, say A and B, sharing common resources like images. The common resources are placed in a war module in a separate project E. And this war file is added as dependency in all the war modules in projects A and B. Currently we are using maven resource plugins to copy these common resources to the root of A and B modules.

How can we do the same action using Gradle?
I am trying this with below configuration, but the files are not copied in to the generated war file. They are only copied to build/libs folder.

```
    configurations {
        commonWebResources
    }
    task extractApi(type: Copy) {
        print 'File : ' + configurations.commonWebResources.singleFile
        from zipTree(configurations.commonWebResources.singleFile)
       into file("${project.buildDir}/libs/")
    }

    compileJava.dependsOn(extractApi)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have common resources like images that I want a build task to generate, I do the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.srcDirs += "src-gen/main/resources"
    }
}
// (include your configurations block and extractApi task here)
processResources.dependsOn extractApi
task cleanGen << {
    file('src-gen/main/resources').delete()
}
clean.dependsOn cleanGen
```